# TreeView - Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I have a problem with binding a class to my `TreeView`. It doesn't really work, I get nothing shown.

This is my class:

```
public class Main
{
    public List<Child1> Ch1 { get; set; }

    public List<Child2> Ch2 { get; set; }

}

public class Child1
{
    public String CName { get; set; }
    public List<Grandson> Grandson { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class Grandson
{
    public String GName { get; set; }
    public List<Son> Son{ get; set; }
    public List<Daught> Daught{ get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class Son
{
    public String OName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class Daught
{
    public String DName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class Child2
{
    public String C2Name { get; set; }
    public int Rights { get; set; }
}
```

As you see, I've got a lot of lists and lists in lists which I want to put in a TreeView.

```
<TreeView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Main}" IsEnabled="{Binding TreeEnabled}" >
    <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding CName}" ItemsSource="{Binding Ch1}" >
        <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding GName}" ItemsSource="{Binding Grandson}" >
            <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding OName}" ItemsSource="{Binding Son}" >
            </TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding DName}" ItemsSource="{Binding Daught}"></TreeViewItem>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeViewItem>
    <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding C2Name}" ItemsSource="{Binding Child2}"></TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

I think I've got a problem with my bindings, but don't know what problem.

Comment: To start with, `ItemsSource="{Binding Main}"` won't work, because there is apparently no property `Main` somewhere. You should assign an instance of class Main to the DataContext of your view. Then you must not explicitly create TreeViewItems when you bind ItemSources. Instead, declare [HierarchicalDataTemplates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: In a hierarchy, a grandson would just be a person several levels down. I think you should either just have a class Person or a Person base class you inherit from. Each person would have a Children property which was  ObservableCollection<Person>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all : you must made `ObservableCollection <T>` when you want to bind a list to view , otherwise it wont show the changes to the view. (I do not know how familier you are with C# , then I say in `<T>` , T means any type you are making a list of them. e.g. `ObservableCollection <Person>`).

Second : If you bind the whole list to a treeview there is no need to bind one by one.

Third : Did you set your DataContext for you bindings any where ?

you need to do something like this in codebehind :

```
this.DataContext = new Class();
```

and then bind to this Class properties. This Class should be your main class in viewmodel.

Comment: Thanks now with ObservalbleColletions at least a part of it works.
But there is still an Issue with the SubList(now also a Colletion).
Have you a hint on this issue as well?

Comment: If you want bind a peroperty to an element in UI, the class owner of that propery must Implement INotifyProPertyChanged inteface, I think it is the other problem of your code.

Answer (score 0):

In my ViewModel i have a Instance of main also named main so it should bind it.

The Hierarchy is given i get i from the database the names are only examples.

The View must look like this

[image]